# Parameter passed with react-navigation's navigate('routeName') is not reactive

Tags: react-native, mobx, react-native-navigation

I'm doing an e-commerce app with react-native. On the products screen, I use FlatList to display all the products stored in a MobX observable array, when you tap on a product I pass that product (object) as parameter with react-navigation's navigate to another screen (ProductDetails), where one can add/reduce the quantity and finally can add that item to the Cart. But, in the ProductsDetails screen the quantity is not reactive.

The qty does get updated in the store, I see that when I go back and come again to the ProductDetails screen.

I've tried looking around at different articles but couldn't really find something that works for me. Any help would be appreciated.

```
//in Products List page

onPress = (item) => { // onPress of a FlatList item
 this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetails', {
            product: item
  })
}
```

```
//in ProductDetails screen

export default class ProductDetails extends Component {

    product = this.props.navigation.getParam('product')

    addQty = () => {
         this.product.qty = this.product.qty + 1;
    }

... (other code)
}
```

Comment: Hi @hong develop, I tried that but with no success. passing 'item' as an object wasn't necessay, I changed that. The qty does get updated in the store but is not reactive.

Comment: Hi @Gaurav, thanks for contributing, I understand your point but what I want is 'ProductsDetails' screen re-rendering everytime addQty is called. ```this.navigation.push('WhateverScreen')``` renders the screen when the screen itself is called. I anyway tried that as well, but still not working.

Comment: Hi @Israt, thanks for answering. That seems to be a workaround to me though, can mobX not track observables through react-navigation?

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this?

```js
onPress = (item) => { // onPress of a FlatList item
 this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetails', {
            product:  item 
  })
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`this.props.navigation.push('ProductDetails', {product: { item } })`
try to use push to re-render the component again, what .navigate does is it checks in the navigation stack and if its there then it doesnt renders again. but push always re-renders the component. so try that.

Answer (score 0):

This problem will be solved by React Native Event Listeners ([react-native-event-listeners](https://github.com/meinto/react-native-event-listeners)). 
 Add EventRegister

```js
//in Products List page

import { EventRegister } from 'react-native-event-listeners'

  componentWillMount() {
        this.listener = EventRegister.addEventListener('myCustomEvent', (item) => {
          console.log(item);
  // update quantity here
        })
    }
    
    componentWillUnmount() {
        EventRegister.removeEventListener(this.listener)
    }


//in ProductDetails screen
  
 EventRegister.emit('myCustomEvent', item)
```

Answer (score 0):

Like the other said above:

```
this.props.navigation.navigate('ProductDetails', {product: { item } })
```

but they forgot to add the usage with params, so to use params inside `ProductDetails`:

```
this.props.navigation.state.params.product
```

Comment: Hi Idan, It doesn't seem to work again. Are you saying that the passed params would become reactive when passed through push ? AFAIK push is the same as navigate, just that it doesn't look into the stack but creates a new instance of the screen. Correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Sorry, not push, i changed again for the correct way

Comment: Sorry Idan, it still doesn't work. What I'm currently doing is storing the navigation params into the local state and updating the state in addQty, this works but is a workaround. Thanks for contributing!

Comment: what doing when you try my code? and the screens in the same stackNavigator ?

Comment: Although the store object does get modified but is still not reactive.

Comment: store? what about store? you try to pass params between component without store not?

Comment: Yes, I meant that value gets updated, but I don't see it updating immediately but only when I go to another screen and then come back to the ProductsDetails screen.